# Is it possible to access alarms set through the iOS clock app?

Tags: ios, ios9, ios10

I would like to trigger events based on when an alarm is set, both at the time that it is set and when it goes off.  I'd rather not have to reinvent the alarm clock app!

Answer (score 6):

There is no API for you to access the user's alarms. You can make your own notifications using [Local Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH102-SW1).

Comment: Actually, is this something that would be possible with HomeKit?